# Errors when making circular reference imports

Tags: objective-c, import, compiler-errors

My program was running fine, but I changed something and now it has over 48 errors.

I think I know the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. I created a class called `mViewBase` for all my `UIViewController`s to derive from.

I decided to have a navigtion bar at the bottom of all my views, to go to other view controllers called `cakes2`.  So cakes2.h imports `mViewBase`, and `mViewBase` import cakes2.h

You must be able to do this in Objective-C. Does anybody have any idea of what I can do?

My mViewBase.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Cakes2.h"

@interface mViewBase : UIViewController {
    UIView *mBackground;
    UIView *mBackArrow;
    UITextView *mTitle;
    //    Cakes2 *mCakes;
}

-(void) aSetTitle: (NSString *) NewTitle;
-(IBAction) aBack: (id) tender;
-(IBAction) aHome: (id) sender;
-(IBAction) aCakes: (id) sender;
-(IBAction) aCall: (id) sender;
-(IBAction) aDirections: (id) sender;
@end
```

My Cakes2.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Gallery.h"
#import "WebView.h"
#import "mViewBase.h" // Circular reference! But I need it

@interface Cakes2 : mViewBase <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    //    Gallery *mGallery;
    IBOutlet UITableView *mMenu;
    // WebView *mWebView;
}
-(IBAction) aOpenWeb;
@end
```

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619075/possible-circular-reference-problem

Comment: are you sure that's the problem? According to some poking around I've just done "the #import directive ensures that files are imported (included) just once per compilation" in objective-c.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a forward declaration in one of your header files to avoid the need to import the other header. For example, in mViewBase.h, you can say:

```
@class Cakes2;
```

Now the compiler knows that "Cakes2" refers to a class, and you don't need to import the entire Cakes2.h file.

Comment: Try and include as few files as possible in.h files, prefer @class forward declarations.  A header file is designed to expose the public interface of the class.

Comment: Hi this did the trick I put the @class in header file and the import in the m file :)  Thank you, Ted

Answer (score 0):

I think you should perhaps consider using a `UITabBarController`. It is made specifically for managing several view controllers from a bar at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment, I was thinking about that, but my project is almost done and did not want to tear up the code.