# Linker "Duplicate Symbol" error due to circular reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, circular-reference

I have two header of a class and it's extension(generated by Xcode for NSManaged object). But I'm getting a linker error and I figured out it was due to a circular reference.

**Conversation+CoreDataClass.h**

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Conversation : NSManagedObject

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

#import "Conversation+CoreDataProperties.h"
```

**Conversation+CoreDataProperties.h**

```
#import "Conversation+CoreDataClass.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Conversation (CoreDataProperties)

+ (NSFetchRequest<Conversation *> *)fetchRequest;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

You can clearly see the circular reference here. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221174/errors-when-making-circular-reference-imports) where the problem was to add a `@class` declaration and remove the header. So I commented out the `import` statement in the `Conversation+CoreDataProperties.h` and added `@class Conversation;`. Now two errors pop up saying it's an undefined class. Have attached the screenshot of the error below. I don't quite understand why this is happening and what I need to do to fix it. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

**Linker error**

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Conversation in:
>       /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-gbhivuwptwzhkldfbmjghkokozgn/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Conversation+CoreDataClass.o
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Conversation in:
>       /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-gbhivuwptwzhkldfbmjghkokozgn/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Conversation+CoreDataClass.o
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ConversationDate in:
>       /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-gbhivuwptwzhkldfbmjghkokozgn/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ConversationDate+CoreDataClass.o
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ConversationDate in:
>       /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-gbhivuwptwzhkldfbmjghkokozgn/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ConversationDate+CoreDataClass.o
>   ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: That's a bit strange. Try cleaning your project (shift-cmd-K) and rebuild.

Comment: @dirkgroten That didn't help. Still have the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41129002/3066450). I just had to remove the .m files from the Compile Sources.

Answer (score 0):

> So I commented out the import statement in the Conversation+CoreDataProperties.h and added @class Conversation;.

You may only do this if you're aren't using any of the `Convention` class's interface (for instance declaring a property of type `Convention`. You can't do this if you're extending `Convention` via a category or class extension.

You have a legit circular reference here you must resolve.  You can either:

1. Move the class and the category into the same source file (if there's no special reason this needs to be in a category you could just move the declaration of `fetchRequest` into the class itself).
2. Stop importing `+CoreDataProperties.h` in the class header, and import it instead wherever callers need to be calling `fetchRequest`.

Comment: Doing the changes makes it compile, but I'm still getting the linker error for duplicate symbols. I've added the error in the question

Answer (score 0):

the duplicate symbols warning do result because

1. You have the class multiple times in your project and the compiler does not know, which to choose (then it is mostly a duplicate linking error)
2. There is something wrong with your *ConversationDate+CoreDataClass*

Just a question that raised from your source code: why do you import an extension of the class you want to extend?

```
#import "Conversation+CoreDataClass.h"
@interface Conversation (CoreDataProperties)

+ (NSFetchRequest<Conversation *> *)fetchRequest;

@end
```

All the extension class usually needs to know are basically the classes they extend:

```
#import "Conversation.h"
@interface Conversation (CoreDataProperties)

+ (NSFetchRequest<Conversation *> *)fetchRequest;

@end
```

Only the implementation file (.m) would have to import the header file. E.g:

```
#import "Conversation+CoreDataClass.h"
@implementation Conversation (CoreDataProperties)

+ (NSFetchRequest<Conversation *> *)fetchRequest { 
    // body
    return nil;
}

@end
```

And last question: Are you sure there exists no other class extension with the same name in your project? CoreData might also have created them itself.

Please have a look in your xCode Project like this:
[image: Use lookup functionality on the bottom left of xCode]

Comment: I found the solution to the problem, posted an answer. Also, there weren't any duplicate files present. For the question `why do you import an extension of the class you want to extend?`, this was automatically generated by Xcode :) Although removing the import statement nor moving the extension code into the class directly didn't seem to help me with the issue.

Comment: Cool! Don't forget to mark your own answer as solution, so the thread can be closed :)

Comment: I can mark it as answered only after a day. Will do it tomorrow :)